# Calling method within Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

im new in ruby so this code is not working, please provide me the proper way of calling a method within class

```
Class TestClass

  def testMethod
    puts "hello"
  end

  testMethod
end
```

*UPDATE*

hi everyone thanks for all the help and comments just like @Stefan and @Matt said, my example is very uncommon to use this way and thanks for giving the right path anyway i just want to add this from my question and i found a way to work

```
class TestClass
    def self.testMethod
       puts "hello"
    end

    TestClass.testMethod
end
```

Comment: please, try to read some tutorials before asking.

Comment: yes, this is quite basic - you may need to read some base tutorials first. To call the method on the object, you have to create an instance of the object and call the method on the object aka send the message testMethod to this instance of TestClass.

Comment: It's common to declare methods within the class body and to call other methods from within these methods. But it's very unusual to call methods directly from within the class body. Although you can do this, it is most likely not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class TestClass
    # a class method
    def self.test_method
       puts "Hello from TestClass"
    end

    # an instance method
    def test_method
       puts "Hello from an instance of TestClass"
    end
 end

 # call the class method
 TestClass.test_method


 # create and instance object of TestClass
 instance_of_TestClass = TestClass.new

 # call the instance method of the new object
 instance_of_TestClass.test_method
```

Comment: Since the OP is new to Ruby, a static output like `puts "hello from class method"` would probably be easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call method in with in class like:

```
class TestClass

  def testMethod
     puts "hello"
  end
  def test_2
    testMethod
  end
end

object = TestClass.new()
puts object.test_2
```

Comment: `class` instead of `Class`

Comment: You could also define it as a class method by doing `def self.testMethod`. Then you'll be able to use it outside of an instance method.

Comment: What's the purpose of `test_2`?

Comment: for calling the instance method in the class

Comment: That's obvious, but why not just `object.testMethod`?

Comment: @Stefan there may be cases where you need to call an instance method within the class. This answer is ok

Comment: @svelandiag sure, but that's not what the OP is asking about. My point was (almost 7 years ago) that it looks as if you need to add a method in order to call a method. Which is not the case – you can call `testMethod` method right away once you have an instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your example defines a class with an instance method. You then try to call the instance method from the class - this won't work.

Instead, you need to call the method as in instance, or convert it to a class method.

```
class TestClass

  def self.testMethod
     puts "hello"
  end

  testMethod 
end
```

Instance and class level distinction is a fundamental concept, you would benefit from taking some tutorials, start with a read of http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/

Comment: `Class TestClass`?

Comment: @Ilya Be more specific in your comments, please. I have edited what I *think* you are referring to.

Comment: @ilya That's just unnecessarily rude and adds nothing to the thread.

Comment: Oh, sorry for my rudeness, I really thought like I said and wanted to delete my comment at once after your quick fix of it. I'll be more specific next time.

Comment: Maybe it was not something that a newcomer needs, but I think every Ruby and Rails developer should understand this syntax. Thanks, @Matt.